# 508 compliance issue with tabbing through "Nice Menus" in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, section508

I have created a custom theme in Drupal 7. I added the "nice menus" module to it. Somewhere in the process I have lost the ability to tab through my pop-up menu on the homepage (For 508 compliance). Can anyone suggest to me the files I need to look at within the (standard) "nice menus" module for Drupal 7 or code I need to look at in my custom page.TPL or CSS to fix the ability to tab through my page menu links?

I was trying to search for any background on 508 compliance issues with the standard "nice menus" module for Drupal 7 but it seems that most people who use it don't have 508 as a primary concern, there wasn't much background online on this issue (that I could find).

I am unable to post source code due to the rules of my project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a link to where you can get the package or a general demo? The information I found was 5 yrs old and wanted to make sure I was looking at the correct thing .